# Ubuntu 14.04: Can't change AMD DPM settings (radeon)

Tags: ati, radeon, fan

Good morning everyone. I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Fresh release) and I wanted to give a serious try to the radeon drivers (AMD 280X). One thing I noticed for the OSS drivers compared to the Catalyst ones is that the fan speed is high at all times. According to most documentation online, I should be able to change settings related to it by

```
# echo battery > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_state
# echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

But both return to me

```
No such file or directory
```

If I do a dmseg|grep radeon I can see the dpm is active

```
[   12.624293] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Since I have a iGPU, the device was card1 and not card0. Hence why I couldn't change the power related files.

Answer (score 0):

AMD does release a driver of its own. You can download the driver from AMD, but be warned, when a release of Linux kernel is updated, it'll crash your X server (GUI process), at least for Ubuntu. I have Radeon HD8970m, and once I faced it.

Comment: The fan speeds work correctly with fglrx (AMD closed source drivers) but I prefered the Open source ones since they are more stable, but the only problem I have with them are just the fan speed when in 2D mode, which, are quite high.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for didn't get you right in the first place. Well, good luck on your discovery.